# Is there a way to inform users about a change in Stash repository?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-server

I would like to know if it is possible to send an e-mail notification to certain users when there is a modification to a particular directory within a repository in Stash. I know it is possible to write a shell script within Jenkins project to do this and then inform through e-mail but I would like to know if there is a native option within Jenkins configuration to this action.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible [within BitBucket Server itself](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/05/07/beautiful-and-relevant-notifications/) as of May 7, 2013:

> **Repository subscriptions**
>
> [...] At times, you may want to receive emails on specific types of messages you care most about including:
>
> - ...
> - Commits – when a new commit is added or a comment is left
> - ...

See also [Manage Inbox and email notifications](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-inbox-and-email-notifications-325321743.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But could you let me know which version of Stash(BitBucket) that you are using. I am using v2.12.3 but i cannot find all the options under Manage Account section.

Comment: @Aditya I'm using Stash 3.1 and it isn't there either. Functionality isn't added to older versions just because of a product rename or merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Poll SCM under Build Triggers section. 
Define a job that uses GIT plugin, specify a workspace and machine so it'll always be synced with the latest, and poll every 2 minutes. if there is a change in the repository the job will be triggered. Add a post build action to send emails using the built in email notification or using [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). 
Don't forget to edit the SMTP information under Manage Jenkins->Configure.

You can check [Here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Polling+for+changes) for more information about Jenkins Polling.